# Change HTML attribute with JavaScript from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, attributes

I have this two HTML elements which are hidden and should become visible when someones enters wrong credentials.

**Username**:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger login_alert" id="username_alert" role="alert"><span>Your username is incorrect. Please try again.</span></div>
```

**Password**:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger login_alert" id="password_alert" role="alert"><span>Your password is incorrect. Please try again.</span></div>
```

In php, when a password is wrong, I try this line:

```
echo '<script>console.log("Error: Password incorrect"); document.getElementById(password_alert).style.display = "block";</script>';
```

This console.log is displayed in the console, but after that I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: password_alert is not defined
    at login.php:15
```

This while `password_alert` is defined in my `div`. 
I also tried this using `ClassName()` by creating two `login_alert` classes for both username and password, but that isn't working either.

Comment: should be `"password_alert"` with quotes, since it's a string - the name of the ID in your document. This has nothing to do with PHP, it's a straight JS syntax error.

Comment: @RobinZigmond please see my response below.

Comment: that error means the element doesn't exist when the script is being run. Are you trying to output the script in the `<head>` of the HTML? It should be at the bottom of the `<body>` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Efectively you have to change the

`document.getElementById(password_alert)`

For

`document.getElementById("password_alert")`

From the definition of getElementById 
[Manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, by changing `(password_alert)` to `("password_alert")` I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by moving the whole PHP section to the end of the HTML `<body>` as advised by @RobinZigmond.